# How to get class index from hovering Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to create a system that when I hover over a specific div, specific text relating to that div appears. Each div is in the same class, with info at a different div with corresponding indexes. I was wondering if there was any way that I could get the class index of each div by hovering over them in order to show hidden information about them. (by showing the hidden info divs).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var allPeople = [];

function win (name, info){
 this.name = name;
 this.info = info;
}

allPeople[0] = new win ("Shelly", "Is Cool");
allPeople[1] = new win ("Brandon", "Likes to golf");
allPeople[2] = new win ("Steve", "Plays Football");
allPeople[3] = new win ("Mia", "Is a good cook");

var i = 0;
$('document').ready(function(){
 for (i = 0; i < allPeople.length; i++){
  $("body").append("<div class='people'> " + allPeople[i].name +" </div>");
  
 }
 for (i = 0; i < allPeople.length; i++){
  $("body").append("<div class='info'> " + allPeople[i].info +" </div>");
 }
});

</script>
<style>
body {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
div {
 background-image: url("http://themes.wdfiles.com/local--files/semi-trans/semi-transbgtransparent.png");
 color: white;
 padding: 2%;
 margin: 2%;
 border: 3px white solid;
}
.info {
 display: none;
 border-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not give your `div` tags a `dataset` attribute? Use the index `i` of your for loop to get the value of the `dataset` and then use a query selector to target the relevant `info` class? or a much simpler method would be to taget the hovered element and use `.next()` to get the `info`

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution can be based on saving the index of each div at creation time as a data attribute like:

```
$("body").append("<div class='people' data-index='" + i +"'> " + allPeople[i].name +" </div>");
```

```js
var allPeople = [];

function win (name, info){
    this.name = name;
    this.info = info;
}

allPeople[0] = new win ("Shelly", "Is Cool");
allPeople[1] = new win ("Brandon", "Likes to golf");
allPeople[2] = new win ("Steve", "Plays Football");
allPeople[3] = new win ("Mia", "Is a good cook");

var i = 0;
$('document').ready(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < allPeople.length; i++){
        $("body").append("<div class='people' data-index='" + i +"'> " + allPeople[i].name +" </div>");

    }
    for (i = 0; i < allPeople.length; i++){
        $("body").append("<div class='info' data-index='" + i +"'> " + allPeople[i].info +" </div>");
    }
    $('.people').hover(function(e) {
        $('.info').eq($(this).data('index')).show();
    }, function(e) {
        $('.info:visible').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
div {
    background-image: url("http://themes.wdfiles.com/local--files/semi-trans/semi-transbgtransparent.png");
    color: white;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 2%;
    border: 3px white solid;
}
.info {
    display: none;
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

You can use [jQuery.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

```js
var allPeople = [];

function win (name, info){
    this.name = name;
    this.info = info;
}

allPeople[0] = new win ("Shelly", "Is Cool");
allPeople[1] = new win ("Brandon", "Likes to golf");
allPeople[2] = new win ("Steve", "Plays Football");
allPeople[3] = new win ("Mia", "Is a good cook");

var i = 0;
$('document').ready(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < allPeople.length; i++){
        $("body").append("<div class='people'> " + allPeople[i].name +" </div>");

    }
    for (i = 0; i < allPeople.length; i++){
        $("body").append("<div class='info'> " + allPeople[i].info +" </div>");
    }
    $('.people').hover(function(e) {
        $('.info').eq($(this).index() % 4).show();
    }, function(e) {
        $('.info').eq($(this).index() % 4).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
div {
    background-image: url("http://themes.wdfiles.com/local--files/semi-trans/semi-transbgtransparent.png");
    color: white;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 2%;
    border: 3px white solid;
}
.info {
    display: none;
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A different approach can be based on filtering the array elements ([Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) in order to get the index of corresponding div.

```js
var allPeople = [];

function win (name, info){
    this.name = name;
    this.info = info;
}

allPeople[0] = new win ("Shelly", "Is Cool");
allPeople[1] = new win ("Brandon", "Likes to golf");
allPeople[2] = new win ("Steve", "Plays Football");
allPeople[3] = new win ("Mia", "Is a good cook");

var i = 0;
$('document').ready(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < allPeople.length; i++){
        $("body").append("<div class='people'> " + allPeople[i].name +" </div>");

    }
    for (i = 0; i < allPeople.length; i++){
        $("body").append("<div class='info'> " + allPeople[i].info +" </div>");
    }
    $('.people').hover(function(e) {
        var txt = this.textContent.trim();
        var peopleInfoIDX = 0;
        allPeople.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
            if (ele.name == txt)
                peopleInfoIDX = idx;
        });
        $('.info').eq(peopleInfoIDX).show();
    }, function(e) {
        $('.info:visible').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
div {
    background-image: url("http://themes.wdfiles.com/local--files/semi-trans/semi-transbgtransparent.png");
    color: white;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 2%;
    border: 3px white solid;
}
.info {
    display: none;
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very nice! Didn't think of `.index()` I will keep that in mind for future. +1

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having a linear set of divs where some are people and others are info, you can nest the info with its corresponding people div so that you can target the correct info with CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="people-container">
  <div class="people">Shelly</div>
  <div class="info">Is Cool</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.people-container:hover .info {
  display: block;
}
```

So when someone hovers over the person's name, the info can be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest and non-messy solution would be to output the index onto the div using a `data-index` attribute.

```
$("body").append("<div class='people' data-index="+ i +"> " + allPeople[i].name +" </div>");
```

and later retrieve the data-attribute value with

```
console.log($(e.target).data('index'))
```